# 'Required parameter 'adminPassword' is missing (null)", while creating vmss with ssh key auth via azure python sdk

Tags: azure, ssh-keys, azure-python-sdk, virtual-machine-scale-set

I am trying to create virtual machine scale set via azure python sdk and I am using the following JSON patter object argument

```
{
   "name":"TEST_CLUSTER",
   "location":"westeurope",
   "sku":{
      "tier":"Standard",
      "capacity":1,
      "name":"Standard_B1s"
   },
   "virtual_machine_profile":{
      "storage_profile":{
         "image_reference":{
            "id":"some_id",
            "offer":null,
            "sku":null,
            "version":null
         },
         "os_disk":{
            "caching":"ReadWrite",
            "create_option":"FromImage",
            "disk_size_gb":30,
            "managed_disk":{
               "storage_account_type":"Premium_LRS"
            }
         }
      },
      "os_profile":{
         "computer_name_prefix":"TESTAMSETUP",
         "admin_username":"testuser",
         "admin_password":null,
         "linux_profile":{
            "disable_password_authentication":true,
            "provision_vm_agent":true,
            "ssh":{
               "public_keys":[
                  {
                     "path":"/some/key/path",
                     "key_daya":"some-key-data"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "patch_settings":{
               "patch_mode":"ImageDefault",
               "assessment_mode":"ImageDefault"
            }
         }
      },
      "network_profile":{
         "network_interface_configurations":[
            {
               "name":"testnetworkinterface",
               "primary":null,
               "ip_configurations":[
                  {
                     "name":"testnetworkinterface",
                     "properties":{
                        "subnet":{
                           "id":"some_id"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "upgrade_mode":"Manual",
   "upgrade_policy":{
      "mode":"Manual"
   }
}
```

I would expect the vmss to be created with ssh key authentication, as far as I have specified `disable_password_authentication` as `true`, but after running my script I get the following error message.

```
Error azure_create_scale_set.py: (InvalidParameter) Required parameter 'adminPassword' is missing (null).
Code: InvalidParameter
Message: Required parameter 'adminPassword' is missing (null).
Target: adminPassword
```

I found a [github issue](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/54767) related to the same  problem. However for OP in github the problem was resolved by setting `disable_password_authentication` as `true`. My question is how to create vmss with azure python sdk with just ssh-key authentication option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how to create vmss with Azure python sdk with just
> ssh-key authentication option.

You can use the below code to create a virtual machine scale set with **`ssh-key`** authentication option by `disable_password_authentication` as `true` using Azure Python SDK.

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

credential=DefaultAzureCredential()
subscription_id="xxxx"
client=ComputeManagementClient(credential=credential,subscription_id=subscription_id)

response = client.virtual_machine_scale_sets.begin_create_or_update(
        resource_group_name="xxxx",
        vm_scale_set_name="xxxx",
        parameters={
            "location": "eastus",
            "properties": {
                "overprovision": True,
                "upgradePolicy": {"mode": "Manual"},
                "virtualMachineProfile": {
                    "networkProfile": {
                        "networkInterfaceConfigurations": [
                            {
                                "name": "<Your vmss name>",
                                "properties": {
                                    "enableIPForwarding": True,
                                    "ipConfigurations": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "<Your vmss name>",
                                            "properties": {
                                                "subnet": {
                                                    "id": f"/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_grp_name}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<Virtualnetwork name>/subnets/< Subnet1 >"
                                                }
                                            },
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "primary": True,
                                },
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "osProfile": {
                        "adminPassword": "xxxx",
                        "adminUsername": "xxxx",
                        "computerNamePrefix": "xxx",
                        "linux_configuration": {
                            "disable_password_authentication": True,
                            "ssh": {
                                 "publicKeys": [
                                     {
                                         "keyData": xxxx",
                                         "path": "xxxxx"
                                     }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "storageProfile": {
                        "imageReference": {
                            "offer": "UbuntuServer",
                            "publisher": "Canonical",
                            "sku": "16.04-LTS",
                            "version": "latest",
                        },
                        "osDisk": {
                            "caching": "ReadWrite",
                            "createOption": "FromImage",
                            "managedDisk": {"storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"},
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            "sku": {"capacity": 3, "name": "Standard_D1_v2", "tier": "Standard"},
        },
    ).result()
print(response)
```

**Output:**

```
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/vmss326', 'name': 'vmss326', 'type': 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets', 'location': 'eastus', 'tags': {'azsecpack': 'nonprod', 'platformsettings.host_environment.service.platform_optedin_for_rootcerts': 'true'}, 'sku': <azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_03_01.models._models_py3.Sku object at 0x000002658300F2D0>, 'plan': None, 'identity': None, 'zones': None, 'extended_location': None, 'upgrade_policy': <azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_03_01.models._models_py3.UpgradePolicy object at 0x000002658300D5D0>, 'automatic_repairs_policy': None, 'virtual_machine_profile': <azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_03_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachineScaleSetVMProfile object at 0x000002658300EC90>, 'provisioning_state': 'Succeeded', 'overprovision': True, 'do_not_run_extensions_on_overprovisioned_v_ms': False, 'unique_id': '40ebf654-e85a-4a7b-932a-b65e0c8b4a14', 'single_placement_group': True, 'zone_balance': None, 'platform_fault_domain_count': None, 'proximity_placement_group': None, 'host_group': None, 'additional_capabilities': None, 'scale_in_policy': None, 'orchestration_mode': 'Uniform', 'spot_restore_policy': None, 'priority_mix_policy': None, 'time_created': datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 13, 15, 11, 17, 573683, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '+00:00'>), 'constrained_maximum_capacity': None}
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

1. [Virtual Machine Scale Sets - Create Or Update - REST API (Azure Compute) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machine-scale-sets/create-or-update?view=rest-compute-2023-07-01&tabs=Python#create-a-scale-set-with-os-image-scheduled-events-enabled.)
2. [How to create a VM with an existing/stored SSH key pair? · Issue #25990 · Azure/azure-sdk-for-python · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/25990) by Wzb123456789.

**Update:**

```
 "osProfile": {
                    "adminUsername": "azureuser",
                    "computerNamePrefix": "vmss326",
                    "linux_configuration": {
                        "disable_password_authentication": True,
                        "ssh": {
                             "publicKeys": [
                                 {
                                     "keyData": "xxxx",
                                     "path": "xxxx"
                                 }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
```

Without passing **`adminPassword`** parameters in the code the virtual machine scale set is created successfully with SSH authentication.

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, I still don't understand why would it still request `adminPassword` option, even though I set `disable_password_authentication` as `true`.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan Check the updated answer without `adminPassword` option I can able to create a Virtual machine scale set with `SSH` authentication.

Comment: Can you also specify with versions of packages and api template you have used to create the template, and also the version of python which is used to run the script? I still get the error when I try the suggested way.

Comment: I used `azure-mgmt-compute==30.0.0` and `azure-identity==1.15.0` packages I taken as reference from this Ms-document  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machine-scale-sets/create-or-update?view=rest-compute-2023-07-01&tabs=Python#create-a-scale-set-with-os-image-scheduled-events-enabled  Create a scale set with a marketplace image plan.